# Mounting a virtual SD to /dev/mmcblk0

Tags: linux, mount, partition, sd-card

I have a compiled program that saves files to an SD card. In the system I'm developing there's no SD card. I need the output to be written to the disk.

How can I mount a partition to act as it was an SD card (on `/dev/mmcblk0`, `/dev/mmcblk0p1`)?

UPDATE

This helped me achieve it:

```
touch /dev/mmcblk0p1
mount --bind /dev/mtdblock7 /dev/mmcblk0p1
mknod /dev/mmcblk0 b 179 0
/bin/mount -t jffs2 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
```

Comment: I don't get it - do you want to write directly to the device and not to the mountpoint?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, the problem is the compiled binary is set to write only on the SD card

Comment: Try making `/dev/mmcblk0` a symlink to an existing device. But be careful and don't overwrite your own disk.

Answer (score 1):

Bind mount it over your `/dev/mmcblk0`, either directly the regular file:

```
# touch /dev/mmcblk0
# mount -B /path/to/disk.img /dev/mmcblk0
```

or if that program is not fooled by it and expects a block device with partitions and such, through a loop device:

```
# kpartx -va /path/to/disk.img
add map loop0p1 (254:0): 0 33552384 linear 7:0 2048
# touch /dev/mmcblk0 /dev/mmcblk0p1
# mount -B /dev/loop0 /dev/mmcblk0
# mount -B /dev/loop0p1 /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Unmount them and remove the mappings after having finished with it:

```
# umount /dev/mmcblk0 /dev/mmcblk0p1
# kpartx -d dummy
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
```

If this is not a one-time action, you may consider using a mount namespace, see [unshare(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html).

Comment: Can I just mount it to a different partition (Not an *.img)

Comment: Surely you can, but __check twice or thrice__, so you don't trash your disk: `mount -B /dev/sda17 /dev/mmcblk0p1`. It's a MUCH BETTER idea to use a virtual disk image (that you can easily create with `truncate`) and THEN copy the data to the real partition.

Comment: I get this error message when trying to mount the partition  `mount: mounting /dev/mtdblock7 on /dev/mmcblk0p1 failed: Input/output error`

Comment: If I were you, I would just run the whole thing into a vm, instead of risking to have my machine trashed by some dubious program which cannot be told what file/devices to use.

Comment: Don't forget the `-B` or `--bind` option.